# Как передать переменную из JavaScript в php?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

У меня есть скрипт который срабатывает каждый `10` секунд. Каждый раз когда она срабатывает значение переменных меняется.

Например первый раз когда она срабатывает `sheep=sheep11`, потом  `sheep=sheep12`, `sheep=sheep13`, `sheep=sheep14` и т.д. Мне надо вот этих `js` переменных передать в `php` и вывести их когда она меняется, то есть каждый раз когда `10` секунд проходит. Я пытался сделать с помощью `ajax`, и методом `get` но все тщетно.

```
var i=11;
var sheeps="sheep";
function funcBefore(){
var sheep= sheeps+(i++);                    
}
count = 0;
intervalId = setInterval(function(){
   count++;
   if(count == 10){
      clearInterval(intervalId);
   }
funcBefore();
}, 1000);`
```

Comment: Очень полезно прочитать: http://phpfaq.ru/newbie/na_tanke

Comment: @Ипатьев Вау, эта статься отвечает примерно на каждый пятый вопрос на StackOverflow (русской и анлиской версии) с тэгом PHP и JavaScript :). Добавил себе закладки.